# Set-builder Notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, predicate-logic

In set-builder notation we describe a set in the following way:

$A=\left\{x:\phi (x)\right\}$

Is it correct to say the following?

1. Fix any $x_{0}\in X$
2. Evaluate the predicate $\phi(x_{0})$
3. $x_{0}\in A$ **if and only if** $\phi(x_{0})$ is true

I am not sure about the "if and only if" part.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: The set $A$ is, by definition, the collection of elements that satisfy $\phi$. Since we define $A$ this way, it is true that $x \in A$ iff $\phi(x)$.

Comment: I don't know what the purpose of 1 and 2 are, but generally "$y\in \{x:\phi\}$" is just notation for "$\exists z(y\in z\wedge \forall x(x\in z \leftrightarrow \phi))$", so 3 is an immediate consequence.

Comment: I'd call this class-builder notation though

Comment: I would translate $A=\left\{x:\phi (x)\right\}$ as $\forall x:[x\in A\iff \phi(x)]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can read A as " The set of all $x$ such that $\phi (x) $ is true". If $x \in A$ then we know that $\phi(x)$ is true. If $\phi(y)$ is true, then $y$ must belong to the set of all $x$ such that $\phi(x)$ is true. And so we have that $x \in A$ iff $\phi(x)$ is true.